# Matching the same rows in a data frame multiple times by order of match

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying subset rows in a data.frame by matching a value in each row by multiple values in another data.frame. However, I don't just want a single match, I want duplicate matches to repeat the row in the order they are matched. For example:

Example Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(1,1,2,3,4))
df2 <- data.frame(c=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3), d=c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3))

df1:
a b
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4

df2:
c d
1 1
1 1
2 2
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
5 5
4 4
3 3
```

Matching by a and c. This does not duplicate the rows

```
df1[df1[,1] %in% df2[,1],]

#Output
a b
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4

#Desired output
a b
1 1
1 1
2 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
5 4
4 3
3 2
```

I feel like this should be simple to do, but I can't seem to locate another answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can use `match` :

```
df1[match(df2$c, df1$a), ]

#    a b
#1   1 1
#1.1 1 1
#2   2 1
#2.1 2 1
#3   3 2
#4   4 3
#5   5 4
#5.1 5 4
#4.1 4 3
#3.1 3 2
```

This works nicely because all the values in `c` column of `df2` is present in `a` column of `df1`. In general case, when there are some values in `c` that do not match it will return `NA` which we can remove using `na.omit`.

```
df1[na.omit(match(df2$c, df1$a)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use simple indexing to replicate the rows in `base R`

```
df1[df1$a[df2$c],]
#    a b
#1   1 1
#1.1 1 1
#2   2 1
#2.1 2 1
#3   3 2
#4   4 3
#5   5 4
#5.1 5 4
#4.1 4 3
#3.1 3 2
```

Comment: That's not giving me the desired output. The only values returned should be from df1, not df2.